# UWP Xaml Binding properties to an other page in a splitview

Tags: properties, binding

i need a little hand on this please,

Context : Windows 10 UWP Development, C#, Visual Studio 2017

I don't understand why I can pass INotify properties in my code, but i can not in the GEDContenuPage page view, that I want to add in the left pane of my SplitView.

```
<SplitView Grid.Row="1" 
    IsPaneOpen="{Binding IsGEDOpen}"
    DisplayMode="Inline" 
    OpenPaneLength="{Binding GEDPaneWidth}">
    <SplitView.Pane>
        <Grid>            
            <v:GEDContenuPage Visibility="{Binding IsGEDOpen, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"  /> 
        </Grid>
    </SplitView.Pane>    
    <ScrollViewer >
        <Grid x:Name="mainGridData" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</SplitView>
```

IsPaneOpen="{Binding IsGEDOpen}" will works and do its job (open or close left pane)

BoolToVisibilityConverter is in app.xaml and works well (tested somewhere else)

I have also created a DependencyPropertyin my page control :

```
<v:GEDContenuPage 
Visibility="{Binding IsGEDOpen, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" 
ext:GEDContenuPageExtension.ContenuId="2446"
/>
```

Same thing here, 2446 will works well, This will open my left pane with the right content. 
But I i try to replace it with a Binding :

```
ext:GEDContenuPageExtension.ContenuId="{Binding GedContenuId}
```

It won't work.

I guess this is end of the week, and the only thing I need is a fresh beer to put things right in my mind...

For your information, the left pane will receive other page than GEDContenuPage. This is why I need a visibility property for each page.

Thanks for help,

Answer (score 0):

OK this was a datacontext issue, this done the trick

```
<Grid Name="parentGrid">

<v:GEDContenuPage Visibility="{Binding DataContext.IsGEDOpen, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, ElementName=parentGrid}" />
```